# How to orderby conditionally using lambda and non lambda linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

In the below code:

```
var results = from service 
              in LogisticsService.GetTransportationModes<CarrierTransportationMode>
              (
                  x => x.CarrierId == carrierRoleId && 
                       x.ParentTransportationModeId != null &&
                       !(x is LoadCarrierMode) &&
                       (x.ParentTransportationMode.TransportationModeStatus != null) &&
                       x.ParentTransportationMode.TransportationModeStatus.Value != TransportationModeStatus.Inactive
               )
                       //.OrderByDescending(o => o.IsDefault)
                       //.ThenBy(t => t.ParentTransportationMode.Name)
               orderby service.IsDefault descending, service.ParentTransportationMode.Name
               select new
               {
                   text = service.ParentTransportationMode.Name,
                   value = service.ParentTransportationMode.Id
               };
```

If `service.IsDefault` is null, I need to skip orderby / thenby completely. So the code would execute as if there was no orderby present in the linq like below:

```
var results = from service 
              in LogisticsService.GetTransportationModes<CarrierTransportationMode>
              (
                  x => x.CarrierId == carrierRoleId &&
                       x.ParentTransportationModeId != null &&
                       !(x is LoadCarrierMode) &&
                       (x.ParentTransportationMode.TransportationModeStatus != null) &&
                       x.ParentTransportationMode.TransportationModeStatus.Value != TransportationModeStatus.Inactive
              )
              select new
              {
                  text = service.ParentTransportationMode.Name,
                  value = service.ParentTransportationMode.Id
              };
```

I tried to modify the query with conditions like below:

```
.OrderByDescending(o => o.IsDefault.HasValue ? o.IsDefault : null)
.ThenBy(t => t.IsDefault.HasValue ? t.ParentTransportationMode.Name : null)
orderby !service.IsDefault.HasValue ? null: service.IsDefault descending, service.ParentTransportationMode.Name
```

But that didn't help.

Do I need to pass any special parameter in the orderby so that the ordering will never happen at all conditionally? any keyword like 'case' or so can be used? If so, how?

Would appreciate any help!.
Thanks!.

Comment: Do you want all elements with `service.IsDefault == null` to be before or after the all elements with `service.IsDefault == null`?

Comment: Well, if service.IsDefault == null, i want all the elements to be in the same order they were fetched from the database. Only if any of the elements have a service.IsDefault == true, should we consider ordering and in no other case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you need to keep the order of the elements with `service.IsDefault == null`, an easy solution is to split your dataset into two parts (first `service.IsDefault == null`, second: service`.IsDefault != null`) sort the second part, then, concat:

```
var transportationModes = LogisticsService.GetTransportationModes<CarrierTransportationMode>(x =>
                              x.CarrierId == carrierRoleId &&
                              x.ParentTransportationModeId != null &&
                              !(x is LoadCarrierMode) &&
                              (x.ParentTransportationMode.TransportationModeStatus != null) &&
                              x.ParentTransportationMode.TransportationModeStatus.Value != TransportationModeStatus.Inactive)

var services = (from service in transportationModes
                where service.IsDefault == null
                select service).Concat
               (from service in transportationModes
                where service.IsDefault != null
                orderby service.IsDefault descending, service.ParentTransportationMode.Name
                select service);

var results = from service in services
              select new
              {
                  text = service.ParentTransportationMode.Name,
                  value = service.ParentTransportationMode.Id
              };
```

Comment: That`s a great soultion. Thank you very much Cédric Bignon!.